# Ember & Mongoose: "Assertion failed: No model was found for '__v'"

Tags: javascript, node.js, ember.js, mongoose

I've got a basic Ember app to create and edit blog posts, and I'm using Ember, Ember-Data, and Mongoose. I can't figure out why, but whenever I submit an edit for a post, it logs the following error in the Chrome console:

```
Assertion failed: No model was found for '__v'
```

For those not familiar with Mongoose, it automatically add `__v` to your documents for versioning. I tried to remove it via normalizeHash, and Ember Inspector shows that it's not in the data in the browser, but the error still magically appears:

```
App.ApplicationSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  primaryKey: "_id",

  normalizeHash: {
    posts: function(hash) {
        console.log("That's a hash");
        delete hash.__v;
        return hash;
    }
  }
});
```

I also tried to cheat, and just add the `__v` to my model to have it dealt with there, but I still get the same error:

```
App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
    title:          DS.attr(),
    post_content:   DS.attr(),
    tags:           DS.attr(),
    creationDate:   DS.attr(),
    author:         DS.attr(),
    complete:       DS.attr(),
    __v:            DS.attr()
});
```

The data is still persisted to the server, so the server has no issue with what's going on. It was originally just an annoying error message that didn't seem to have any negative consequences, but when I tried to add a `didUpdate` listener to stay on the page until I got the success event, it wouldn't execute the callback.

```
post.one('didUpdate', this, function() {
    // redirects to post itself
    this.transitionToRoute('post', post);
});
```

Any idea on how to handle the `__v` properly? If I can't beat it into submission, I'm just going to tell Mongoose to stop creating them, but I'd rather keep the versioning in the documents.